# Are there any mining pools operating on the Testnet?

Tags: mining-pools, testnet, testing

Are there any mining pools operating on the Bitcoin Testnet, or do pool owners just test their code using their own machines without keeping the test pool up for too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, one can merge mine at this pool on the Test Net:

- https://alpha.masterpool.eu/

Comment: I get "the requested URL can not be found"